# Coloring the output of conky-cli in dwm

Tags: arch-linux, sed, dwm

I've recently installed `conky-cli` and got it running on the upper bar in `dwm` with this simple command:

```
conky | while read -r; do xsetroot -name "$REPLY"; done &
```

And I wanted to get colored output with conky, thought this could be done with `sed` like:

```
conky | sed .. | while ..
```

But don't know how to get the output from the pipe with sed and convert it to a color.

Comment: What output is conky-cli returning?

Answer (score 1):

To get colours in dwm's status bar with `conky` you have two options:

- patch dwm with the [statuscolours patch](http://dwm.suckless.org/patches/statuscolors)<sup>1</sup> and use `conky-cli` with the `exec` variable for the coloured text.
- pipe conky to [dzen](https://github.com/robm/dzen) and let `dzen` handle the colourizing (this is more of a hack as it paints over the dwm bar).

A third approach, which I find much cleaner<sup>2</sup>, is to patch dwm with statuscolours and use a shell script to write the various system information to the root window: [screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jasonwryan/8165934321/in/photostream).

<sup>1. See my bitbucket repo for a statuscolours patch for [dwm 6.0](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/dwm-patchset/src/4b30b835aec076e3e5fda611fbc1faa3fed1789a/statuscolours?at=default)</sup>
<sup>2. You can also find my statusbar script in my [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/1409cefda536e07f03a2ee7036c094a15973d43d/Scripts/dwm-status?at=default).</sup>

Comment: Thanks , I'll try this asap, I'm sure I'll find it useful.